# ¿Como hacer un server multiprocesos? -Server-multiprocessing-

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket

Necesito un servidor el cual pueda responder a varias peticiones post que se le pidan y retorne su respectiva respuesta.

Mi código representa un simple server pero solo hace un petición a la vez.
Soy nuevo utilizando multiprocessing, no sé como implementarlo correctamente.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Autor: Diego Lopez

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import multiprocessing
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import SocketServer
import json
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import signal

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>hi!</h1></body></html>")

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        # Doesn't do anything with posted data
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
        self._set_headers()
        try:
            data_string = json.loads(post_data)
        except:
            self.wfile.write('{"error" : "JSON"}')
            return

        placa = str(data_string["placa"])
        placa = placa.encode("utf8")
        print post_data
        scraping(placa,self)


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=6464):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print 'Starting httpd...'
    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(httpd.serve_forever())
    server_process.daemon = True
    server_process.start()



def scraping(placa,self):
    self.wfile.write(placa)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

Comment: ¿cual es su pregunta?

Comment: ¿Como hacer un server multiprocesos?

Comment: Esa pregunta es demasiado amplia, lea las reglas de [ask], pienso que usted deberia saberlo ya que tiene suficiente reputacion.

Comment: Pregunto porque no sé como hacer que cree los procesos secundarios mientras recibe peticiones.

Comment: No se en donde me puedan ayudar mas que este sitio.

Comment: Crea un hilo que maneje a cada cliente

Comment: Me darías algún ejemplo.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins

Comment: Eso no soluciona mi problema solo es la creacion de un server normal como el que poseo.

Comment: No se crean procesos o hilos, los cual quiero hacer pero nos e

Comment: no es lo mismo, el servidor hereda de SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, ya implementa el multiprocesamiento

Comment: Yo recibo información por método post con el cual empiezo a realizar la lógica, eso serviría igualmente?

Comment: Sabes como implementar eso con el código que escribí arriba?

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a la pregunta era un poco complicada pero encontre un codigo funcional que me sirvio para lo que necesitaba.

Usar ThreadedHTTPServer e implementarlo así.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import threading
class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        message =  threading.currentThread().getName()
        self.wfile.write(message)
        self.wfile.write('\n')
        return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Handler)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: jajaja, es el mismo ejemplo del tutorial... lo recomendable es publicar el ejemplo con tus modificaciones.

Comment: Una pregunta, cuantos procesos tolera el server?